# Retrofit android timeout with local host

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a WebApi project on localhost but routed with Node IIS Express Proxy that produces the current address (Ethernet: 192.168.0.100:3000), if I try to call from Postman, it works, but not on Android.

[image]

Here's what I did :

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.100:3000";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .create();
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(defaultClient())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

private static OkHttpClient  defaultClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                    readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                    writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                    addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Hawk.get("t"))
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }).build();
}
```

And the Call :

```
private RetrofitEndpoint retrofitEndpoint;

Service() {
    retrofitEndpoint = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitEndpoint.class);
}

@Override
public void register(OnFinishedListener listener, SignModel model) {
    Call<Token> call = retrofitEndpoint.SignIn(model);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Token> call, @NotNull Response<Token> response) {
            listener.onFinished(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Token> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            listener.onFailure(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably the firewall is blocking access. Try whitelisting the port 3000.

Comment: If you use emulator your localhost ip is :10.0.2.2 by the way what the error log say?

Comment: I'am routing with IIS Express, i'm using a physical device!

Comment: to debug retrofit please use logging interceptor check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408981/slim-retrofit-android-studio-apprequests-not-working/59436452#59436452 hope this help